# Matrix multiplication giving NA

Tags: r, matrix

I'm attempting to do simple matrix multiplication, that has never given me this issue before.

I have an X matrix (nxfe) and a matrix of observations, y (nx1). For the purposes of this example lets just say

```
X <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=4)
y <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow=4)
```

simple code for this multiplication is

```
Xt <- t(X)
Xy <- Xt%*%y
```

however, when I do this, I get a matrix of NA's (nx1).

This has never happened before. I have checked and there are appropriate values in all my matrices. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess that you masked `%*%` from some package and it overrides ```base::`%*%```. Does ```base::`%*%`(Xt, y)``` works?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem but you could have created `X` using `diag(4)`.

Comment: Does `crossprod(X, y)` work?

Comment: I used the "base" suggestion and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: I wonder what package you have loaded that overrided `%*%`...